# Is it possible to add type information at compile time?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have the following code:

```
function addProperties(keys: String[]): Object
{
    // For the sake of example, this is a concrete return
    return {
        firstProperty: "first_value",
        secondProperty: "second_value"
    };
}

export default {

    propertyBag: {
        ...addProperties(["firstProperty", "secondProperty"])
    },

    someMethod() {
        return this.firstProperty;
    }

};
```

Typescript naturally complains that `firstProperty` does not exist on this object.

Is it possible to 'dynamically' add the type information to let TS know that both `firstProperty` and `secondProperty` exist on this object?

Ideally I'd like to be able to do this without having to have a separate definition for `propertyBag`, as suggested in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where `addProperty` comes from and what the definition of that is, but assuming that it returns an object with the properties specified as parameters, you can specify that `someMethod` will have a `this` parameter that is the same type as the property bag. The only catch is you need to separate the definition of the `propertyBag` from the `export default`:

```
const propertyBag = {
    ...addProperties(["firstProperty", "secondProperty"])
};
export default {
    propertyBag,
    someMethod(this: typeof propertyBag) {
        return this.firstProperty;
    }
};

// Assumed definition 
function addProperties<T extends string>(a: T[]) : { [P in T]: any} {
    return null as any;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Having to separate the definition is really what I'm trying to avoid here; I should clarify that in my question. I will also add a dummy definition of `addProperties` as you've rightly suggested.

Comment: @NilsLuxton the only other option is to use an explicit type for `this` or use a helper function .. but the helper function is not going to make the code look any prettier, I can share what I have if you wan't but I am not particularly happy with it myself

Comment: To be honest, anything you have is helpful - I'm quite new to TS so any additional knowledge is welcome! :)